# Ruby on Rails: sign out isn't working for devise with User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, devise

I have the following routes:
I'm developing an exercise tracking app and I want to have `tracked_exercises` for the currently logged in user. This is my `routes.rb` file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :exercises
  devise_for :users
  resources :users do
    resources :tracked_exercises
  end
  root to: 'exercises#index'
end
```

However when I'm trying to log the current user out with `<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: "navbar-link"  %>` I first run into an error that says `Uninitialized constant UsersController`.
Then after creating it, it turns out the redirection points the users to `users/show`, and after having this controller, the logout never works:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Am I doing something wrong with the way I've set devise up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`method: :delete` for links was a Rails UJS thing.

```rb
<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path,
  data: {turbo_method: :delete}
%>

# or better use a form
<%= button_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path,
  method: :delete
%>
```

*https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#hotwireturbo*

Comment: Using `button_to` fixed it, thanks a lot! I'll go ahead and read Devise's Hotwire update :)